# Implementing "where not exists" with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Using the new `QueryOver` API in NHibernate, I need to do something equivalent of:

```
select c.*
from Category c
where not exists (
    select *
    from CategoryProduct cp
    where cp.CategoryID = c.Id
    and cp.ProductID = 'DogFood'
)
```

In other words: "Give me all categories that doesn't contain dog food".

My initial thought was something like:

```
IEnumerable<Category> FindCategoriesWithoutProduct(Product product)
{
    return _session
        .QueryOver<Category>()
        .Where(c => c.Products.Contains(product))
        .List();
}
```

However, this makes `NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor` blow up with an "unrecognised method call" on `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Contains()`.

I assume there must be some other way to do this, probably involving an `ICriterion`, but my searches here and on Google have returned nothing useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just running in the same problem, and possible solution is:

```
Category aliasCategory = null;
CategoryProduct aliasCategoryProduct = null;

var qcp = QueryOver.Of<CategoryProduct>(() => aliasCategoryProduct)
          .Where(() => aliasCategoryProduct.ProductID == "DogFood")
          .Where(() => aliasCategory.Id == aliasCategoryProduct.CategoryID)
          .DetachedCriteria;

return _session.QueryOver<Category>(() => aliasCategory)
               .Where(Subqueries.NotExists(qcp));
```

It works on my similar criteria.

Comment: Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection.

It requires some kind of projection (i.e. select clause)

Comment: Actually, there is selection. Look at QueryOver.Of<CategoryProduct>... Of<CategoryProduct> defines projection.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but something like this

```
IEnumerable<Category> FindCategoriesWithoutProduct(Product product)
{
    CategoryProduct categoryProductAlias = null;
    var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<CategoryProduct>(() => categoryProductAlias)   
        .Select(x => categryProductAlias.ID)
        .Where(() => categoryProductAlias.ProductID == "DogFood");

    Category categoryAlias = null;
    return _session
        .QueryOver<Category>(() => categoryAlias)
        .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => clientAlias.Id).NotIn(subQuery)
        .List();
}
```

Comment: Where is the "cp.CategoryID = c.Id" restriction? Shouldn't you have a "Where(() => categoryProductAlias.CategoryID = categoryAlias.ID)" in the detached query?